# How to subset data from multiple dataframes for a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to calculate the weekly price change in a list of products that I have, but I am having issues even pulling in the values. `df1` is a list of products and the dates I am interested in, `df2` is the price history of all products. I want to add a new column to df1 with the % price change for 1 week (1 week from date in df1)

```
df1:                
Item    Date       1W Px Change
A       1/1/17     
B       2/1/17
A       2/2/17
C       2/2/17
D       3/1/17

df2:
Date      A    B    C    D
1/1/17    1    5    10   50
1/2/17    2    5    9    40
1/3/17    3    5    10   42
```

The dataframes have thousands of products and dates. I tried with a `for loop` to create a new vector with just the price from the day in `df1` but getting a `replacement has length zero` error.

```
price <- rep(NA,nrow(df1))
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
    price[i] <- df2[which(df2$Date==df1$Date[i]),df1$Item[i]]
  }
```

Any ideas on how to either fix the for loop, or if there is a better way for me to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possible problems with this approach. First issue might be with comparing times. Check if you really have same time format in both tables and that they compare as you expect.

Second, you don't consider `NULL` being returned. Try this modification

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
   value <- df2[which(df2$Date==df1$Date[i]), df1$Item[i]]
   if(!is.null(value)) price[i] <- value 
}
```

And lastly, check that you have `df$Item` as character and not factor. Otherwise you might be getting weird outcomes (factors in `df1$Item[i]` are returned as `Int`, not as `char`)